# how to choose path to save excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am able to enter the name of the file i want to save as however, how do you add in the path of which i want to save the excel file in?

this is the code i use

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Module.Text + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Comment: use this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/savefiledialog-component-overview-windows-forms (SaveFileDialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just can combine your file path and file name.

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs($@"c:\{Module.Text}" + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the first parameter you can not only specify the file name but also the location.

Example:

```
wbook.SaveAs("c:\\file_path\\file_name",  Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to the file name, in the first parameter:

```
book.SaveAs(@"C:\Book1.xml"...
```